# Is there a built-in markdown flavor for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, markdown

I like to use markdown languages like GitHub markdown and ASCIIDoc to provide lightweight formatting to text documents.  The tags in HTML are too heavy and render the original text almost unreadable.

The problem is when I send documents to other users. They can't be bothered with installing a markdown plugin. I would like to use a markdown flavor that will render predictably in web browsers. That way I can send a URL for my document and the recipient will see the formatted text.

Is there a standard markdown language built into Firefox?

Thanks,

(PS: this is a serious question. Pedants please restrain yourselves.)

Comment: No, as far as I know no major web browsers natively render Markdown. There may be plugins that do. (Of course, you could render your Markdown to HTML locally and send the output files.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, at the moment, there are no major web browsers that natively support parsing and rendering markdown.
However, there are a few solutions.

1. Render the markdown to html and send the html document. Most renderers automatically include Stylesheets that make the html look good, or you can edit the output or templates yourself.
2. Get the recepent to install a extension that will render the markdown. I quickly found something by googling firefox markdown extension.

I hope this solved your problem.